# What is the purpose of balancing a redox half equation using H+ and H2O and electrons?

Tags: physical-chemistry

Is it possible to say that:

1. H+ is used due to the provision of an acidic medium?
2. H2O used as it is an aqueous medium and products have oxygen, so logically oxygen must come from H2O?
3. Electrons added to conserve charge?

Comment: You must have heard about the fundamental conservation laws od nature. The consequence is, if the equation is not balanced, it is wrong. Note that $\ce{H+}$ is just a convenient simplification of $\ce{H3O+ . n H2O}$

Comment: that doesn’t explain why it must be added using those... i can easily add oxygen gas to balance...

Comment: I was addressing the title. The title is in agreement with the body, isn't it ? BTW, try to reformulate the body, it is not very easy to understand, what you mean.

Comment: You can add anything, but it may not follow the reality. Equations describe what reacts and what are the products.

Comment: It is not about what is used, but what mutually interact and react. E.g. $$\ce{2 H3O+ + 2 e- -> 2 H2O + H2(g)}$$

Comment: how is this rule even generalised? I mean the fact that H+ and H2O is always used, you’re saying that every redox half equation has it? sorry i’m very confused by this... i always thought there was a purpose to it (like the one i highlighted in the qn since that’ll make sense)

Comment: It is not tule, it is following the reality. And no, I am not saying H+ and H2O is always used. Where are they in Cu2+ + 2 e- -> Cu ? The best would be the illustration on particular full reaction and its separation to half reactions in the question.

Comment: What about balancing redox reactions in aqueous base? No protons available there.

Answer (score 1):

One reason to track solvated hydrogen (or hydroxide) ions and water in a redox reaction is that the hydrogen ions often get transferred too, and you need to know how that takes place to render the products.  We should expect hydrogen-ion transfers as part of the process in a protocol solvent such as water or a concentrated protic acid, as **the electrons are charged and some compensating charge-transfer process must take place to keep the charges in balance.**

Copper in concentrated nitric acid, where nitrogen is reduced (primarily) to the +4 oxidation state, is a well-worn example.  The oxidation half-reaction is, of course, copper being oxidized to $\ce{Cu(II)}$.  So we look at the reduction half-reaction.  In its "raw" form we would have

$\ce{HNO_3 -> NO2}$

We balance the elements other than hydrogen and oxygen, which is already done, and then compare the combined oxidation states of those elements in the reactants and products to find that the nitric acid must have taken one elecron:

$\ce{HNO_3 + e^- -> NO2}$

Now the charges are not balanced, and so we invoke that compensating hydrogen ion transfer.  In acid this is set up by adding (solvated) hydrogen ions to balance the charges:

$\ce{HNO_3 + \color{blue}{H^+} + e^- -> NO2}$

Water is used to balance the hydrogen which, if we did things correctly, balances the oxygen as well giving our familiar result

$\ce{HNO_3 + H^+ + e^- -> NO2 +H2O}$

and upon combining with the copper oxidation:

$\ce{Cu + 2 HNO_3 + 2 H^+ -> Cu^{2+} + 2 NO2 + 2 H2O}$

in which we see that in the final reaction, hydrogen ions are indeed transferred.  So we needed to account for them.